# Is there a way to tell from SIP SDP to check if PBX is using inband dtmf?

Tags: sip, dtmf

Just in case when PBX is using RFC 2833 outofband DTMF, it says Payload Type 101, is there a similar way to check for inband DTMF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can check from the SDP for inband DTMF, as in that case DTMF is passed along with the negotiated audio codec as audio tones, hence there is no related attribute in the SDP that would characterize it. You could probably check your actual media from the .pcap, but not sure that would work for you.